# The $\infty$-category of natural transformations as an end

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff, infinity-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an $\infty$-category viewed as a fibrant scaled simplicial set with all 2-simplices thin and let $\mathfrak{C}\!at_{\infty}$ be the $\infty$-bicategory of $\infty$-categories. A model for $\mathfrak{C}\!at_{\infty}$ is given by applying the marked version of the homotopy coherent nerve to $\operatorname{Set}_{\Delta}^{+}$.

We define the $\infty$-bicategory of functors $\operatorname{Fun}(\mathcal{C},\mathfrak{C}\!at_{\infty})$ as in the $(\infty,1)$-case. Thin 2-simplices are given by maps of simplicial sets $\mathcal{C}\times \Delta^2_{\sharp} \to \mathfrak{C}\!at_{\infty}$ where $\Delta^2_{\sharp} $ denotes the maximally scaled 2-simplex.

Given two functors $F,G: \mathcal{C} \to \mathfrak{C}\!at_{\infty}$ we can use Proposition 2.4 in [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.01905.pdf)  to compute a model for $\operatorname{Nat}(F,G)$ in terms of a suitably lax slice construction.

I would like to show that $\operatorname{Nat}(F,G)\cong \lim_\limits{\operatorname{Tw}(C)}\operatorname{Fun}(F(-),G(-))$, which should obviously be true but I am having trouble constructing the universal cone for this functor.

Comment: The version of this statement for functors between two $(\infty,1)$-categories can be found as proposition 2.3 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3065, or in section 5 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.02161 , this is not exactly what you are asking, but maybe this is close enough ?

Comment: @SimonHenry I am aware of those two references. I want to relate Example 6.8 in  the second paper your mentioned with the model of Nat(F,G) above.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an $\infty$-category and $\mathbb{D}$ be an $\infty$-bicategory. In joint work with W. Stern ([Enhaced twisted arrow categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.11969) )  we show that there is a natural equivalence of $\infty$-categories

$$\operatorname{Nat}(F,G) \simeq \lim_{\operatorname{Tw}(\mathcal{C})^{\operatorname{op}}} \operatorname{Map}_{\mathbb{D}}(F(-),G(-))$$

The "op" comes from the fact that we are using right fibration $\operatorname{Tw}(\mathcal{C}) \to \mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C}^{\operatorname{op}}$.